# Value of IPC_CREAT when used in JNA

Tags: java, jna

I need to communicate a java application and a c process via posix message queue, and I am using JNA in java application.

In C process, when create message queue I am using:

```
key_t key = 112233;
int msgflg = IPC_CREAT | 0666;

msqid = msgget(key, msgflg )
```

What is the value of IPC_CREAT to use in Java application?
I found in ipc.h :

```
/usr/include/sys/ipc.h:#define  IPC_CREAT       0001000         /* create entry if key doesn't exist */
```

May I safety assume that I can use 512? (decimal) ?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I java there is no "define" for IPC_CREAT, so I have to replace with the correct value. It will work with '0' just fine, this is why I'm wondering if I can put 512 without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use `950`, because

```
final int IPC_CREAT = 0001000;
int msgflg = IPC_CREAT | 0666;
System.out.println(msgflg);
```

outputs

```
950
```

I may not understand your question, because

```
printf("%i\n", 0001000 | 0666);
```

also outputs

```
950
```

**Edit**

**Yes**.

```
final int IPC_CREAT = 0001000;
System.out.printf("%d%n", IPC_CREAT);
```

Output is 512. And,

```
printf("%i\n", 0001000);
```

Output is 512. So you could use decimal 512. Or the binary version like C.

Comment: Great. Thanks for confirmation.